# Sum of 16 squares?

Tags: number-theory

It is known that for n=1,2,4,8 the sum of squares is multiplicative. See for instance "Naive Lie theory" Stillwell for a good reference. It happens to be that these identities are the result of the existence of Hypercomplex number systems: The reals, the complex numbers, the quarternions, the octonions.

Now with the cayley-dickson process one can produce higher 2^k number systems, the first of which the sedenions is 16-dimensional. Is there a sum of squares identity for N=16, or for genereal 2^k?

That is if a={sum of 16 squares}, and b={sum of 16 squares} is ab={sum of 16 squares}?

Comment: Embarassingly I've just found the answer. The answer is indeed no, proven by Young in 1888. See http://www.academia.edu/1762928/The_history_of_the_2-_4-_and_8-square_identities for a reference.

Comment: The answer is yes, not no.

Comment: This question doesn't specify whether the squares come from a ring, an arbitrary field, a specific field or whatever. No wonder it got different answers!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A sum of squares identity *does* exist for $N = 16$, and in fact when $N$ is any power of 2. For $N$ equal to a power of 2, the set of nonzero sums of $N$ squares in any field $F$ is a subgroup of $F - \{0\}$.

See http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/linmultialg/pfister.pdf for more, and in particular why this does not violate the Hurwitz theorem.

Comment: Can you explicitly provide/construct such an identity for $N = 16$?

Comment: If you google "Pfister 16 square" you find a link to such formulas very quickly.  Look at https://sites.google.com/site/tpiezas/0021c. Note the denominators and the non-bilinear nature of the identity.

Comment: What a great and surprising answer! I've tried to read the references provided, but some of it is a bit advanced. Since you name that this is possible for any power of two, is there a connection between this identity and the hypercomplex numbers of higher dimensionality? And can it be proven that N=2^k are the only solutions?

Comment: @LeeWang: Yes, if $N$ is not a power of 2 then there is some field in which some product of two sums of $N$ squares is not a sum of $N$ squares.

Comment: If you work over rings rather than fields, there is a theorem of Dai, Lam, and Milgram with a conclusion that will sound comforting: if for *all* commutative rings $A$ the set of elements of $A$ that are sums of $n$ squares in $A$ is closed under multiplication then $n = 1$, 2, 4, or 8. This is proved by example: if there were such a formula when $A$ is the localization of ${\mathbf R}[x_1,...,x_n,y_1,...,y_n]$ at the two polynomials $u = x_1^2 + \cdots + x_n^2$ and $v = y_1^2 + \cdots + y_n^2$ then this would contradict a theorem in topology unless $n$ is 1, 2, 4, or 8.

Comment: A reference for the result of Dai, Lam, and Milgram described in my previous comment is Proposition A.2 (p. 253) of Shapiro's "Compositions of Quadratic Forms".

Comment: Here is some more information on why there is not a universal sum of squares product formula for $n$ squares when $n$ is *not* a power of 2. Cassels (1963) showed for any field $F$ in which $-1$ is not a sum of squares that $1 + x_1^2 + \cdots + x_n^2$ is not a sum of $n$ squares in $F(x_1,\dots,x_n)$, where $x_i$'s are indeterminates over $F$. Write $D_K(n)$ for the set of all nonzero sums of $n$ squares in a field $K$. So Cassels's result says $D_K(n)$ is strictly smaller than $D_K(n+1)$ when $K = F(x_1,\dots,x_n)$. If we include more indeterminates ${\mathbf y} = (y_i)$ then [to be contd.]

Comment: the field $-1$ is not a sum of squares in $F({\mathbf y})$ when $-1$ is not a sum of squares in $F$, so $1+x_1^2+\cdots + x_n^2$ is not a sum of $n$ squares in $F(x_1,\dots,x_n,{\mathbf y})$. Therefore by letting ${\mathbf y} = \{x_{n+1},x_{n+2},\dots\}$ and taking $F = {\mathbf R}$ for concreteness, we see that $1+x_1^2 + \cdots + x_n^2$ is not a sum of $n$ squares in ${\mathbf R}(x_1,x_2,\dots)$. Calling this field $K$, the subsets $D_K(1), D_K(2), D_K(3),\dots$ are strictly increasing. So for $m < n$ we have $D_K(m)$ strictly inside $D_K(n)$ for this $K$. In 1965, Pfister [to be contd.]

Comment: showed for every field $L$ and positive integers $r$ and $s$ that $D_L(r)D_L(s) = D_L(r \circ s)$, where $r \circ s$ is a subtle function of $r$ and $s$ that has nothing to do with the choice of $L$ (one formula: $r \circ s$ is the least $n$ for which $(x+y)^n = 0$ in ${\mathbf F}_2[x,y]/(x^r,y^s)$, so $r \circ s \leq r+s-1$). That is, the nonzero sums of $r$ squares times the nonzero sums of $s$ squares in any $L$ is the same as the nonzero sums of $r \circ s$ squares in $L$. In particular, $D_L(n)D_L(n) = D_L(n \circ n)$. It can be shown that when $n$ is not a power of 2 that  [to be contd.]

Comment: $n < n \circ n$, and therefore if we use for $L$ the field $K = {\mathbf R}(x_1,x_2,\dots)$ mentioned earlier, we have $D_K(n)$ a proper subset of $D_K(n \circ n) = D_K(n)D_K(n)$. Therefore in $K$ there is some product of two nonzero sums of $n$ squares that is not a sum of $n$ squares. So the single field $K$ provides an example where the nonzero sums of $n$ squares are not closed under multiplication for $n$ any positive integer that is not a power of 2. (The information I have written about in the comments to this answer is largely based on what I learned from Dan Shapiro.)

Comment: Wow, I think I'll need time to digest all of this, but thanks a lot for this well-informed answer.

Comment: Not sure if this is the best place to report this, but there is a typo on page 1: search for "seach" (it's near the bottom)

Comment: When I mention above the theorem of Dai, Lam, and Milgram, that is somewhat more than is necessary; they proved that *units* equal to sums of $n$ squares are closed under multiplication in all rings iff $n$ is 1, 2, 4, or 8. In order to show that sums of $n$ squares are closed under mult. in all rings iff $n$ is 1, 2, 4, or 8, it is enough to work with  the ring ${\mathbf R}[x_1,\dots,x_n,y_1,\dots,y_n]$ rather than its localization at two polynomials as described above, and in fact everything winds up reducing to the 1,2,4,8 theorem.

Answer (score 4):

After googling some more I've found that not only does the sum of squares not exist for N=16 or N=2^k, the only possible values are just N=1,2,4,8

This theorem, known as Hurwitz theorem, was a vital step in the classification of normed division algebras.

See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normed_division_algebra

EDIT: this is wrong, see above.

Comment: Would it be possible to provide a "counterexample" that verifies that this is not always possible? (i.e., an $a = \sum x_i^2$ and $b = \sum y_i^2$ for which there exist no $z_i$ with $ab = \sum z_i^2$)

Comment: @TMM: There are no counterexamples (in fields).