# Analogue of $(a^2 + b^2)(c^2 + d^2) = (ac - bd)^2 + (ad + bc)^2$ for vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

The Brahmagupta–Fibonacci identity $(a^2 + b^2)(c^2 + d^2) = (ac - bd)^2 + (ad + bc)^2$ allows us to write a product of squares as a sum of squares. Is there an analogue of this identity when $a, b, c, d$ are vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and the multiplication is the ordinary scalar product?

One of the main hurdles is of course $(a \cdot c)(b \cdot d) \neq (a \cdot b)(c \cdot d)$. The [Cauchy-Binet identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binet%E2%80%93Cauchy_identity) gives an expression for  $(a \cdot c)(b \cdot d) - (a \cdot b)(c \cdot d)$, however I do not see a way to turn this into a simple expression.

EDIT: I do not mind having extra terms in the end: something like $(a\cdot a + b \cdot b)(c \cdot c + d \cdot) = (a\cdot c - b\cdot d)^2 + (a\cdot d + b\cdot c)^2 + \mbox{other terms}$ where the remaining terms can be written explicitly.

Comment: Such an analogue (at least understood sufficiently close to the original identity) likely entail that $\left(x_1^2 + x_2^2 + \cdots + x_{2n}^2\right) \left(y_1^2 + y_2^2 + \cdots + y_{2n}^2\right)$ can be written as $u_1^2 + u_2^2 + \cdots + u_{2n}^2$ for some quadratic forms $u_1, u_2, \ldots, u_{2n}$ in the $x_i$ and $y_i$. But such quadratic forms only exist if $n \in \left\{1,2,4\right\}$, according to Theorem 1.1 in [Keith Conrad, *The Hurwitz theorem on sums of squares by representation theory*](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/hurwitzrepnthy.pdf).

Comment: @darijgrinberg that's good to know, thank you!

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/358207/sum-of-16-squares

Comment: Also for $n=8$, corresponds to octonions.

Comment: Now the question is how many "other terms" you're allowing. (Allow too many and you can just expand the left hand side.)

Comment: Frankly I don't know, what I'm looking for, but I don't think it exists unless we just apply the  Binet–Cauchy identity  and make the remainder be "everything else remaining" (which is not helpful). Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume (perhaps unreasonably closed-mindedly) that you want an analogue of the form
\begin{align}
\left(\left<a,a\right>^2 + \left<b,b\right>^2\right) \left(\left<c,c\right>^2 + \left<d,d\right>^2\right) = \left<v,v\right>^2 + \left<w,w\right>^2
\end{align}
that holds for any vectors $a, b, c, d \in \mathbb{Q}^n$, where $v$ and $w$ are two vectors in $\mathbb{Q}^n$ whose entries are fixed degree-$2$ homogeneous polynomials in the entries of $a, b, c, d$. Such an analogue exists only if $n \in \left\{1,2,4\right\}$. Indeed, if we number the entries of the vectors $a, b, c, d$ such that $a = \left(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n\right)^T$ and $b = \left(x_{n+1}, x_{n+2}, \ldots, x_{2n}\right)^T$ and $c = \left(y_1, y_2, \ldots, y_n\right)^T$ and $d = \left(y_{n+1}, y_{n+2}, \ldots, y_{2n}\right)^T$, then the above analogue would imply that the polynomial $\left(x_1^2 + x_2^2 + \cdots + x_{2n}^2\right) \left(y_1^2 + y_2^2 + \cdots + y_{2n}^2\right)$ can be written as $u_1^2 + u_2^2 + \cdots + u_{2n}^2$ for some quadratic forms $u_1, u_2, \ldots, u_{2n}$ in the $x_i$ and $y_i$. But such quadratic forms only exist if $n \in \left\{1,2,4\right\}$, according to Theorem 1.1 in [Keith Conrad, *The Hurwitz theorem on sums of squares by representation theory*](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/hurwitzrepnthy.pdf). (Note that my $2n$ is his $n$.)